# Adding element to DOM but JS doesn't know it's there

Tags: javascript

I am adding an element to the DOM on mouse up of a button being clicked.

The element is adding to the DOM I can see it when I inspect. However within the same mouse up - after adding the element to the DOM - I want to manipulate that element, but I am unable to do so because the new element with it's unique id was not present when the DOM loaded first time around.

I am given this error as the newly created element effectively does not exist: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

How can I 'update' what is present in the DOM so the JS can see what's changed and recognise any new elements and ids?

```js
const likeWrapper = document.getElementById("likeWrapper");
let yourLikeTotal = 0;
let mouseDown = 0;
const yourLikes = document.getElementById("yourLikes_postid_" + yourLikeTotal);

document.body.onmousedown = function() { ++mouseDown }
document.body.onmouseup = function() { --mouseDown }


const addToYourLikes = () => {
  console.log(yourLikeTotal)
  console.log(yourLikes)
  yourLikes.innerHTML = yourLikeTotal
  yourLikeTotal++
  console.log("addToYourLikes");
}

const moveYourLikes = () => {
  yourLikes.classList.add("move-your-likes")
  setTimeout( () => { 
  yourLikes.classList.remove('move-your-likes');
    console.log("remove class")
}, 800);
  console.log("moveYourLikes");
}

const addEl = () => {
  const id = "yourLikes_postid_" + yourLikeTotal;
  const div = '<div id=' + id + ' ' + 'class="your-likes">0</div>';
  likeWrapper.innerHTML += div;
}


likeWrapper.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  /* if mousedown and up execute 1 button animation -
  while mousedown do not end animation, just keep adding to totals
  */
  addEl();
  addToYourLikes();
  moveYourLikes();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  user-select: none;
}

main {
  margin: 160px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.like-button-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.like-button {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.like-total {
  line-height:30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.your-likes {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#989898;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  z-index:0;
  line-height:20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  opacity:1;
}

.move-your-likes {
  -webkit-animation-name: moveLikes;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes moveLikes {
  from { top:0; opacity:0; }
  to { top: -40px; opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
  <div class="like-button-wrapper" id="likeWrapper">
    <div class="like-button" id="likeButton"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. You can just insert your code in a "Code Snippet", right here to be able to have others run it.

Comment: `const yourLikes = document.getElementById("yourLikes_postid_" + yourLikeTotal);` is only executed once whenever the browsers parses and executes the script block. And at that moment there is no element with the id `yourLikes_postid_0` hence `.getElementById()` returns `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want event handlers to attach to dynamically added elements, you must insert them as "nodes" (`document.createElement()`) into the DOM (`.appendChild()`), not as HTML strings (`.innerHTML`).

Additionally, you can't set your DOM `const yourLikes` reference before the element has been created. You have to do that after it's been added to the DOM. So, it will need to be declared as a `var` or `let` variable initially and then initialized only after the DOM element exists in the DOM.

```js
const likeWrapper = document.getElementById("likeWrapper");
let yourLikeTotal = 0;
let mouseDown = 0;
var yourLikes = null; // Can't get reference here. It doesn't exist yet!

document.body.onmousedown = function() { ++mouseDown }
document.body.onmouseup = function() { --mouseDown }


const addToYourLikes = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(yourLikes, yourLikeTotal)
  yourLikes.innerHTML = yourLikeTotal
  yourLikeTotal++
  // console.log("addToYourLikes");
}

const moveYourLikes = () => {
  yourLikes.classList.add("move-your-likes")
  setTimeout( () => { 
  yourLikes.classList.remove('move-your-likes');
    // console.log("remove class")
}, 800);
  // console.log("moveYourLikes");
}

const addEl = () => {
  const id = "yourLikes_postid_" + yourLikeTotal;
  // New elements should be created and inserted as nodes:
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = id;
  div.classList.add("your-likes");
  div.textContent = "0";
  likeWrapper.appendChild(div);
  yourLikes = div;  // Now, set the higher scoped variable to the new element
}


likeWrapper.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  /* if mousedown and up execute 1 button animation -
  while mousedown do not end animation, just keep adding to totals
  */
  addEl();
  addToYourLikes();
  moveYourLikes();
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  user-select: none;
}

main {
  margin: 160px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.like-button-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.like-button {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.like-total {
  line-height:30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.your-likes {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  font-size:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#989898;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  z-index:0;
  line-height:20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  opacity:1;
}

.move-your-likes {
  -webkit-animation-name: moveLikes;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes moveLikes {
  from { top:0; opacity:0; }
  to { top: -40px; opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="like-button-wrapper" id="likeWrapper">
    <div class="like-button" id="likeButton"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The changes to yourLikes make complete sense, I don't think I'd have considered that, beginners mistake. Also good to know about nodes vs just the innerHTML, thanks!